# Is it possible to look up expiration dates for domains in the .DE (Germany) TLD?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains, whois, expires

It appears that running a whois on .DE domains returns almost no information.  Using google.de as an example:

```
$ whois google.de
% Restricted rights.
%
% Terms and Conditions of Use
%
% The above data may only be used within the scope of technical or
% administrative necessities of Internet operation or to remedy legal
% problems.
% The use for other purposes, in particular for advertising, is not permitted.
%
% The DENIC whois service on port 43 doesn't disclose any information concerning
% the domain holder, general request and abuse contact.
% This information can be obtained through use of our web-based whois service
% available at the DENIC website:
% http://www.denic.de/en/domains/whois-service/web-whois.html
%
%

Domain: google.de
Nserver: ns1.google.com
Nserver: ns2.google.com
Nserver: ns3.google.com
Nserver: ns4.google.com
Status: connect
Changed: 2018-03-12T21:44:25+01:00
```

I tried the referenced http://www.denic.de/en/domains/whois-service/web-whois.html site however it returns essentially the same contact (plus an abuse e-mail).

Is it simply impossible for someone other than the owner to look up the expiration date for one of these domains?

Comment: I checked a few online WHOIS lookups, including the registry's as well, and it doesn't seem possible to find either expiration or creation date - only if it's available or registered. Perhaps someone else will know if this data is available through the WHOIS protocol and how to access it.

Comment: .DE registrars should be probably able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

.de domain names, like some other ccTLDs do not have expiry dates. They live on as long as long you pay for them. That's why German providers often charge for the domain names by the month (around €1 or less/month is typical).

Comment: ".de domain names, like some other ccTLDs do not have expiry dates." That is not exactly true. They do have expiration dates but like almost all TLDs, the registry autorenews them on expiration. Hence they appear to be infinite (as long as the registrar doesn't delete them) but they aren't, it is a subscription model like for newspapers. Expiration dates are fully visible by registrars. REgistry (that act as registrar) clearly display the price for one year of service: https://www.denic.de/en/price-list/